# How to do redux-saga combine testing with jest and enzyme

Tags: react-redux, jestjs, enzyme

I have done redux and saga testing but now i want to test combine redux-saga testing with enzyme and jest.is it possible with jest and enzyme

Answer (score -1):

This is more or less the pattern you should follow:

```
// import the saga, types, actions, and api
import { put, call } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import * as saga from './YOUR_SAGA_DIRECTORY';
import * as api from './YOUR_API_DIRECTORY';
import * as actions from './YOUR_ACTIONS_DIRECTORY';
import * as types from './YOUR_TYPES_DIRECTORY';

describe('TEST SAGA WITH JEST', () => {
    // provide mock params for your action
    const param = 'test';
    const anotherParam = 'anotherTest';

    test('SAGA SUCCESS', () => {
        // execute the saga with the action and the mocks
        const generator = saga.yourSaga(actions.yourAction(param, anotherParam));
        expect(generator.next().value).toEqual(call(api.yourApi, param, anotherParam));
        // assert that it was executed successfully
       expect(generator.next().value).toEqual(put(actions.successAction()));

  });

    test('SAGA FAILURE', () => {
        const generator = saga.yourSaga(actions.yourAction(param, anotherParam));
        expect(generator.next().value).toEqual(call(api.yourApi, param, anotherParam));
        // assert that it executed the failureAction after error was thrown
    expect(generator.throw('error').value).toEqual(put(actions.failureAction());

  });
});
```

Note that this is unit testing, where you check that the saga has executed as expected according to the order of actions and effects chain within it. There is more information at [tedux-saga-testing](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/advanced/Testing.html).